# An alternative to global in Python

Tags: python, global

I currently have code like this:

```
cache = 1
def foo():
    global cache
    # many
    # lines
    # of code
    cache = 2
```

However, this may lead to hard-to-find-bugs in the future, because the reader may not notice that `global cache` appears somewhere above `cache = 2`. Alternatively, a contributor may mistakenly add `def bar(): cache = 2` and forget to add the `global cache`.

How can I avoid this pitfall?

Comment: What exactly is the pitfall?  What are you trying to accomplish, and what is not working?

Comment: What if someone writes the second method? It will still be a local variable. There is no issue with your code.

Comment: If there's no `global` declaration, then the variable is local - if 'the reader' has any background in python, then they'll know it's local. If you really want to, just add a comment saying it's local or something.

Comment: When you have a lot of lines of code, it's cumbersome to have to look for 'global cache' somewhere above 'cache = 2'. I posted a work-around answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
class Cache:
     myvar = 1

def foo():
    Cache.myvar = 2
```

This way, `Cache.myvar` is practically a "global". It's possible to read/write to it from anywhere.

I prefer this over the dictionary alternative, because it allows for auto-complete of the variable names.

Answer (score 8):

```
cache = 1
def foo():
    return 2
cache = foo()
```

or

```
d = {'cache': 1}
def foo(x):
    x['cache'] = 2
foo(d)
```

Answer (score 3):

"the reader may unintentionally think that the global variable has been updated" isn't much of a pitfall.  You have to expect that people reading your code know how Python works.  If you want to make it extra clear, use a comment.  That's what they're for.

Answer (score 2):

Using global variable is not a good programming practice. Pass the variable as an argument: make function returns something and use it in another function. Function can be assignment to variable that's how Python works.